# show specific database with session

Tags: php, html, database, session

uservieworder.php

```
   <?php
 include("connect.php");
 session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#919191">

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['ID']))  //Checking if they have the session cookie
{


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN register WHERE customer_id ='".$_SESSION["ID"]."' LIMIT 10");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>User ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Prices</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['customer_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_price'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
}

else
{
    echo "<title>Error!</title>";
    //Doesn't have session cookie
    echo "YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost"; //local server name default localhost
$username="root";  //mysql username default is root.
$password="";       //blank if no password is set for mysql.
$database="register";  //database name which you created
$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database,$con);
?>
```

with the code above , it show every data on the database.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['customer_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_price'] . "</td>";
```

on the code above , ( customer_id, total_price data are from orders table, and Username are from register table )

I wanted that only show specific data based on session id only .

Comment: Do you have select where in your code?

Comment: Put the "session id" in the `WHERE` clause of your `SELECT` query

Comment: the problem now is , the 'customer_id' in order table are ( 'ID' on register table)

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN register WHERE customer_id ='".$_SESSION["ID"]."' LIMIT 10");

Comment: @Tesseract any help on this ?